# What is the difference between homeUrl and baseUrl in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

What is the difference between **homeUrl** and **baseUrl** in Yii framework?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the docs:

**baseUrl:**

> Returns the relative URL for the application. This is similar to
>   scriptUrl except that it does not have the script file name, and the
>   ending slashes are stripped off.

While, **homeUrl** is

> the homepage URL

Try echoing somewhere at your application to examine each by yourself:

```php
echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);// true tells to get a relative url, false the other way
echo Yii::app()->getHomeUrl();
```

**How to use each?**

**baseUrl** is as @bcmcfc said can be useful as a base for all links in your applications.

Now imagine you wanted to link to an image in `web_root/myapp/img/` if for example you did that using  absolute path e.g `<img src="C:/wwww/myapp/img/somepic.jpg>` Let's say you finished all your development and now you want to deploy to some `linux` server!!

You can see that all your links will be broken :( but if instead you did: `<img src= <?php Yii::app()->baseUrl() ?> . "/img/somepic.jpg"` Everything should work fine :)

**homeUrl** is simply the landing page for your app. Well i didn't use this before but i guess you can set diffirent homeurls according to User role after login for example!!

Answer (score 28):

```
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true);   // => http://localhost/yii_projects
Yii::app()->getHomeUrl();       // => /yii_projects/index.php
Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(false);  // => /yii_projects
```

This is the best practice in pointing directory of images etc. or the file itself rather than hardcoding the path which can change name"

Answer (score 1):

One is the base URL for the links in your app. The other is the home URL. The home URL would be based on the base URL and would be a particular route or page, for example, that is redirected to after logging in.