# Dompdf generate with bootstrap and yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, pdf-generation, dompdf

[image]
[image]

Hi, i'm using a framework yii2 with a component DomPDF to generate pdf's from a  GridView::widget to generate a table with bootstrap. but my pdf doesn't look like a bootstrap table and i don't know why, please somebody help me
i use this template:

```
<?php
/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use app\assets\AppAsset;

/*
 * Variáveis Globais
 */
$tituloPrincipal = $this->params['tituloPrincipal'];
//$tituloSecundario = $this->params['tituloSecundario'];
//$utilizador = $this->params['utilizador'];
//$breadcrumb = $this->params['breadcrumb'];
/*
 * *** *** ***
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
<!--       <style>


        #footer2 { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -60px; right: 0px; height: 50px; font-size: 8pt; font-family:  Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        #footer2 .page:after { contentor: counter(page, upper-roman); }
      </style>  -->
        <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/styleImpressoes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
        <!-- font Awesome -->
        <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="cabecalho" style="padding-top: -20px; height: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
            <table id="cabecalho" width="100%">
                <tr>
<!--                    <td>
                        <div style="text-align: left;">
                            <img src="./img/logotipo-vfa2.png" height="75" />
                        </div>
                    </td>-->
                    <td>
                        <div style="text-align: left;">
                            <?php echo $tituloPrincipal; ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div id="contentor" style="width: 100%;">

            <div class="contentRelatorioTemplate">
                <?php
                echo $content;
                ?>
            </div>      
        </div>

        <!--         <div id="footer2" style="border-top: 1px solid black;width: 100%;text-align: right;">
                       <div style="margin-right: 18px;margin-top: 4px;">Pág. </div>
                 </div>-->
        <script type="text/php">
            if ( isset($pdf) ) {

            $pdf->line(34,770,580,770,array(0,0,0),1);

            $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica");
            $pdf->page_text(545, 775, utf8_encode("Pág. {PAGE_NUM} / {PAGE_COUNT}"),
            $font, 8, array(0,0,0));
            $dataImp = date("Y-m-d"); 

            $pdf->page_text(250, 775, "Impresso em: " . $dataImp,
            $font, 8, array(0,0,0));

            $pdf->page_text(35, 775, "Visionsoft",
            $font, 8, array(0,0,0));
            }
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

the view:

```
<div class="cliente-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // var_dump($dataProvider);die;  ?>
    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'assunto_r',
            'descricao_r',
        ],
        'showFooter' => true,
         'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
    ]);
    ?>

</div>
```

the controller:

```
$pdfGen->render('impressao/impressaoAssuntoA4', [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Comment: Share what you tried

Comment: I add my code up in the comment. it seems the dompdf doesn't work with bootstrap

Comment: I replace:
        <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
For:
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
And now obtain this error:
Illegal string offset 'hex'

Answer (score 0):

dompdf will not perfectly render a bootstrap-based layout, but it should be able to render a majority of the styling. Your issue is likely not related to using bootstrap but to the stylesheet not loading.

Please note that I do not know much about Yii, so my analysis is based on some quick [google-fu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16436003/264628) and my knowledge of dompdf.

In your template you reference the stylesheet as follows:

```
<link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/styleImpressoes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`Yii::$app->request->baseUrl` retuns a relative url for the application root (e.g. the path to the root of your web app). Because of how you are loading your document into dompdf the assumption is a URL without protocol and domain are relative to the running script on the file system.

Your URL reference (`<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/styleImpressoes.css`) parses as "/css/styleImpressoes.css" which translates to the path on the filesystem. The easiest fix is to add a protocol and domain to your references using `Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true)`, e.g.

```
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true); ?>/css/styleImpressoes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You could also pass in a full filesystem path (maybe using something like `YiiBase::getPathOfAlias('webroot')`), but if you're sharing this template between web views and PDF rendering that would be problematic.

Comment: I replace: <link href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> For: <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> And now obtain this error: Illegal string offset 'hex

Comment: Now *that* is an error with dompdf's processing of the bootstrap styling. This issue has been addressed in the latest stable version of dompdf.